# How to always show some hidden files in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, nautilus-extensions

I know all the files with dot in front of their names are hidden. Nautilus have an option to hide some specific files without dot in their name – by listing their names in *.hidden* text file, so these files will be hidden too, even if they don't start with dot.

I'm looking for something similar to show only specific hidden files (with dot) by default. Something like a *.shown* file – a list of files to show by default, even if they have a dot in front of their names. I tried to create a *.shown* file, but it doesn't work. Is such an option implemented yet? If not, is there any workaround (without forking Nautilus) or Nautilus extension with that option?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use something like nautilus-hide?

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-hide
nautilus -q
```

Project page: https://github.com/brunonova/nautilus-hide

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to hide files without dot, I want to show files with dot (the opposite). This extension adds nice GUI way to hide files, but it still uses nautilus' *.hidden* file feature and I don't see a way how could I make it work with *.shown* file (which is not implemented in nautilus).

Comment: I see. The problem lies with nautilus not having the opposite functionality of the .hidden file. Perhaps this should be requested as new feature / enhancement to nautilus. There are two routes to go now. Request the functionality upstream here: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=nautilus or find an application to do this. Best of luck.