# Show always one specific hidden file inside a specific folder

Tags: nautilus, hidden-files

I am creating a backup of `.bashrc`. I make a copy of it inside my backup folder.
Let's say the folder is `~/backup`

previously I always created a `.hidden` file and put the name of files I want to hide. But now the case is opposite, I am always trying to show the hidden file.

This is the closest I came across, but no luck !! [Is it possible to have Nautilus show hidden files except for one specific folder?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1114610/is-it-possible-to-have-nautilus-show-hidden-files-except-for-one-specific-folder)
 and [How to always show some hidden files in Nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/677304/how-to-always-show-some-hidden-files-in-nautilus)

I have tried `!.bashrc` in `.hidden` file.

Here is a screenshot to emphasize simplicity. **ANY IDEAS??**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The direct feature to selectively show hidden files is not available. The user case is also not quite clear. In principle, it is easy enough to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> to quickly see a file you know is normally hidden.

There are workarounds you can use to achieve what you want, but unless you indicate why you would want to achieve this, it is a bit guessing.

If the reason is that you want quick access to a hidden file, i.e., for quick opening and editing, then you could create a link to the file, e.g. a link `bashrc` to the file `.bashrc` in the same directory. That is not more overhead than editing a `.hidden` configuration file.

That way, you see a file anytime that gives quick access to the hidden file.

*Hard link or symbolic link?*

In the old days, I would have recommended to make a hard link. However, graphical editors, upon saving, may make a copy and then rename the copy when the changed file is saved. This breaks the hard link. Therefore, I would recommend a symbolic link, that always links to the same file name, even if its inode has changed.

Comment: @ vanadium in my case, I am creating a backup. Usually, we do not need to visit backup in a while and because the file is hidden I might forget I made a backup of it in the first place.

Comment: Press Control+H to see all hidden files you included in the backup.